How to create image(DEM) with countour and buildings shapes
I'm GIS beginner and I'm trying to make a DEM with building's height.
Step 1 > I get a countor shape file.

Step 2 > Generate a DEM.

Step 3 > I get a Buildings shape file.

And then, how can I merge the DEM and Buildings shape?
Finally, I want to get a DEM which has countour and buildings height are merged.

This is not standard procedure, normally, the workflow is inverse: you have a DEM and extract contours. I'm not sure about your final task, please provide more information. Proper DEMs are created from measurement (e.g. with Lidar/Laser), not from vector data. This does not seem to make sense to me.

You can rasterize the buildings. If you have a heigh attribute for each building use it, otherwise you can set a fixed value for all rasters. Set the value to 0 where there isnt a building. Sum the output raster and the DEM

@Bera, Thanks, I rasterize the buildings shape, but the result is differ from my mind. How can I set the value to 0 where there isn't a buildings during rasterizing?

What tool do you use to rasterize

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455612/qgis-dem-adding-height-to-raster
